# Кластерный индекс PK и упорядочивание

Tags: sql-server

> Цитата

Заметил, что с PK и без данные выбираются из столбца одинаково (по порядку их следования в таблице), а при выборке из столбца с кластерным индексом данные упорядочиваются по имени столбца (для строчного типа по алфавиту) так ли это?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *с PK и без данные выбираются из столбца одинаково* - фраза лишена смысла. *данные упорядочиваются по имени столбца* - не бывает от слова "совсем", бессмысленный набор слов..

Comment: Извините, может я не правильно понял (добавил скрин). После добавления кластерного индекса на поле Name таблица стала упорядочиваться по этому столбцу или здесь дело в чем-то другом?

Comment: Это звучит так: "При наличии кластерного индекса записи таблицы при отсутствии отбора и сортировки в тексте запроса (т.е. при простом `SELECT * FROM tablename`) обычно возвращаются в порядке сортировки по выражению кластерного индекса."